# Is this possible to customize the elasticsearch result in magento2?

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2, elasticsearch-7

When i search a product it gives many irrelevant product i want to skip those. Please help if someone know how it is possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To configure the query in the Elastic Search extension, do the following:

Step 1. Make a general configuration of the module by setting up the connection and setting Autocomplete suggestions & Spelling corrections.

Step 2. Then navigate to Admin Panel > Stores > Product and choose a needed attribute.  Next, go to the Storefront Properties option and switch the Use in Search option to Yes to add a product attribute to a search query configuration.

Step 3. Now, go to the Catalog settings section on the Configuration tab and specify the Search Query Settings for each product attribute

Step 4. Specify the way to combine keywords in a search query for each product attribute

Step 5. After that, complete Indexation Settings

Step 6. Save the changes.